# No data display from Angular even though there is no error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a beginner with Java and Angular, and I am following a course about how to start with Angular. I am trying to display information in the navigator but for some reasons nothing shows up. Furthermore, I have checked my code and couldn't find an error(I don't really understand much).

The name of the app is facesnap

`facesnap.models.ts` :

```
export class FaceSnap {
  title!: string;
  description!: string;
  createDate!: Date;
  snaps!: number;
  imageUrl!: string;
  location?: string;
  
}
```

`facensnaps.component.ts` :

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FaceSnap } from '../facesnap.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-facesnap',
  templateUrl: './facesnap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./facesnap.component.scss']
})
export class FacesnapComponent implements OnInit {
  // Creer un component
  @Input() facesnap!: FaceSnap;// importer la classe et pouvoir la modifier

  compter!: number;
  ngOnInit() {// Initialiser les proprietes. Peut se faire en dure ou par requete  
  }

 
  onAddSnap() {// Incrementer le nbre de snaps chq fois qu´on appuie sur le button
    if (this.compter < 1) {
      this.compter++;
      this.facesnap.snaps++;
    }
  }
  



}
```

`app.component.ts` :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FaceSnap } from './facesnap.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', // Grace a ceci, on peut utiliser notre component coe une balise
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  mySnap1!: FaceSnap; //On cree une variable de type FaceSnap
  mySnap2!: FaceSnap;
  mySnap3!: FaceSnap;
 
  ngonInit() {
    this.mySnap1 = {
      title:"Senes",
      description:"Mon meilleur Ami Ennemi",
      createDate:new Date(),
      snaps: 256,
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
      location: "Berlin"
    };
    this.mySnap2 = {
      title: "Blueno",
      description: "Le max",
      createDate: new Date(),
      snaps: 2254,
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
      location: "München",
    };
    this.mySnap3 = {
      title: "Linda",
      description: "Best",
      createDate: new Date(),
      snaps: 93,
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
      
    };
    

  }
}
```

`app.component.html` :

```
<app-facesnap [facesnap]="mySnap1"></app-facesnap>
<app-facesnap [facesnap]="mySnap2"></app-facesnap>
<app-facesnap [facesnap]="mySnap3"></app-facesnap>
```

`facesnap.component.html` :

```
<div class="face-snap-card">
  <h2>{{facesnap.title}}</h2>
  <p>Mis en ligne le {{ facesnap.createDate }}</p>
  <img [src]="facesnap.imageUrl" [alt]="facesnap.title">
  <p>{{ facesnap.description }}</p>
  <p *ngIf="facesnap.location"></p>
  <p> {{ facesnap.snaps }}</p>
  <p>
    <button (click)="onAddSnap()">Oh Snap!</button>
     {{ facesnap.snaps }}
  </p> 
</div>
```

What I get
[image: What i get]

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo? `ngonInit` should be `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1):

@peinearydevelopment is right, you have a typo in the word ngOnInit. You also have to implement the OnInit interface in the AppComponent to trigger the ngOnInit method when the application starts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FaceSnap } from './facesnap.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', // Grace a ceci, on peut utiliser notre component coe une balise
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  mySnap1!: FaceSnap; //On cree une variable de type FaceSnap
  mySnap2!: FaceSnap;
  mySnap3!: FaceSnap;
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mySnap1 = {
      title:"Senes",
      description:"Mon meilleur Ami Ennemi",
      createDate:new Date(),
      snaps: 256,
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
      location: "Berlin"
    };
    this.mySnap2 = {
      title: "Blueno",
      description: "Le max",
      createDate: new Date(),
      snaps: 2254,
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
      location: "München",
    };
    this.mySnap3 = {
      title: "Linda",
      description: "Best",
      createDate: new Date(),
      snaps: 93,
      imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
      
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I didn't notice it at all. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You might what to consider using switch case logic here that way instead of 3 variables you have one and you can just pass the number.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export interface FaceSnap {
   title?: string;
  description?: string;
  createDate?: Date;
  snaps?: number;
  imageUrl?: string;
  location?: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'help-dude';
  snap?:FaceSnap;
  ngOnInit(){
    switch(this.snap?.snaps){
      case(256):{
        return {
          title:"Senes",
          description:"Mon meilleur Ami Ennemi",
          createDate:new Date(),
          snaps: 256,
          imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
          location: "Berlin"
        }
      }
      case(2254):{
        return {
          title: "Blueno",
          description: "Le max",
          createDate: new Date(),
          snaps: 2254,
          imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
          location: "München",
        }
      }
      case(93):{
        return {
          title: "Linda",
          description: "Best",
          createDate: new Date(),
          snaps: 93,
          imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/31/16/03/teddy-bear-792273_1280.jpg",
          
        }

      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your proposition. I wanted to display the 3 variables at the same time. However i did realize that creating a variable each time is time-consuming so i tried an array.